# Create shapefile connecting points "as the crow flies" in R

Tags: r, spatial-statistics

I have a set of locations (with latitude and longitude). I know how to get the distance between these points, but I want to create a line that connects them with the shortest path ("as the crow flies"). I would like the line to be a SpatialLines object.

How do I do this? I tried googling a bit and couldn't find it.

Comment: If the crow flies a fair distance (I.e. a migratory crow) you'd better use Geo methods like gcIntermediate in geosphere

Answer (score 2):

I just released a package "GeNetIt" that contains a function "knn.graph" that will create a saturated graph based on points. You can prune the graph, based on an edge distance criteria, using the "max.dist" argument (see example). The description "as the crow flys" does not provide enough information to ascertain the type of graph you are after but, this may be a good place to start.

Add libraries and example SpatialPointsDataFrame "ralu.site"

```
library(sp)
library(GeNetIt)
data(ralu.site) 
class(ralu.site)
```

Now we can construct saturated and distance constrained graphs and plot results. The resulting graph objects are SpatialLinesDataFrame objects and can be written to a shapefile using readOGR in rgdal.

The drop.diag argument is to remove duplicate edges. The default is FALSE because the function is intended as a helper function in constructing a spatial matrix model (eg., gravity). In matrix models, the edges have to represent from and to flow characteristics and as such, are duplicated. In the case of using this function to construct a more conventional spatial graph you want to drop the diagonal of the matrix (drop.diag = TRUE) thus, removing the redundant edges. However, this is not necessary if a distance constrained graph is specified.

```
# Saturated spatial graph
 sat.graph <- knn.graph(ralu.site, row.names=ralu.site@data[,"SiteName"], drop.diag = TRUE)
  head(sat.graph@data)

 # Distanced constrained spatial graph
 dist.graph <- knn.graph(ralu.site, row.names=ralu.site@data[,"SiteName"], max.dist = 5000)

 par(mfrow=c(1,2))  
plot(sat.graph, col="grey")
  points(ralu.site, col="red", pch=20, cex=1.5)
     box()
     title("Saturated graph")   
plot(dist.graph, col="grey")
  points(ralu.site, col="red", pch=20, cex=1.5)
     box()
     title("Distance constrained graph")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with just `sp`

```
library(sp)

coords <- cbind(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))
points <- SpatialPoints(coords)

all.lines <- list()
for (i in 1:length(points)) {
  l1 <- apply(points[-i]@coords, 1, function(x) Line(rbind(x, points[i]@coords)))
  all.lines <- c(all.lines, l1)
}

sp.lines <- SpatialLines(LinesList = list(Lines(all.lines, ID = "paths")))

plot(sp.lines)
plot(points, add = TRUE, col = "blue", pch = 20)
```

[image]

I'm open to suggestions for improvement.

**EDIT:** The solution above duplicates paths.  You could try a `while` loop to generate unique paths

```
points.copy <- points
all.lines <- list()
while (length(points.copy) > 1) {
  l1 <- apply(points.copy[-1]@coords, 1, function(x) Line(rbind(x,    points.copy[1]@coords)))
  all.lines <- c(all.lines, l1)
  points.copy <- points.copy[-1]
}
```